# Can't define $STEAM_LIBRARY variable for BLT installation

Tags: steam, environment-variables

[image: command line]

When I try to install BLT, the installer can't find the PAYDAY2 location. I've been trying with:

```
STEAM_LIBRARY=/home/scastro81/.steam/steam/ set | grep STEAM_LIBRARY
```

These are the locations where I found the library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Open your `~/.profile` file for editing.
- To the bottom of that file, add this line:

  ```
  export STEAM_LIBRARY="$HOME/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/PAYDAY 2"
  ```
- Save, log out from your session, and log in again.